# ctable width of column, \tnote and pos

Tags: macros, positioning, ctable

Have two problems regarding ctable.

- Have multiple `ctable`s and would like the first column in the tables to have a fixed width (also the tables to have the same total width)?
- When I add a `\tnote[]{}` to the `ctable`, the table is always placed to the center of the page. If i remove the `\tnote`, it is placed according to `pos=`.

EDIT: don't know if it is the `\tnote` which mess things up, but if i have these two tables:

```
\ctable[caption=Second OLS regression table, doinside=\small \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}, pos=ht]{lrrrr}{\tnote[]{OLS regression}}{
 \toprule
 \multicolumn{5}{c}{OLS Regression} \\
 & Estimate & Std. Error & t value & Pr($>$$|$t$|$) \\ 
  \midrule
(Intercept) & -0.13 & 0.07 & -1.76 & 0.08 \\ 
  reserves & -0.29 & 0.54 & -0.54 & 0.59 \\ 
  gsci & -0.52 & 0.32 & -1.62 & 0.11 \\ 
  L.logprem40 & 0.06 & 0.08 & 0.71 & 0.48 \\ 
  q1 & -0.18 & 0.10 & -1.83 & 0.07 \\ 
  q2 & -0.18 & 0.11 & -1.75 & 0.08 \\ 
  q3 & -0.20 & 0.13 & -1.51 & 0.13 \\ 
\bottomrule
}


\ctable[caption=Second quantile regression table I, doinside=\small \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2},pos=ht]{lrrrrrrr}{\tnote[]{Resulte form the second quantile regression on the crude oil inventory, GSCI and lagged premiums 40. Standard errors are bootstrapped with 500 repetitions}}{
\toprule
\multicolumn{8}{c}{Quantreg} \\
variable & $1-\alpha$ & Coefficient & Std.Error & t-stat & Pr$>$$|t|$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{95\% CI} \\ 
  \midrule
Inventory & 0.01 & -0.79 & 0.63 & -1.27 & 0.21 & -1.81 & 0.98 \\ 
   & 0.05 & -1.24 & 0.27 & -4.60 & 0.00 & -1.52 & -0.68 \\ 
   & 0.1 & -0.42 & 0.23 & -1.87 & 0.06 & -0.84 & -0.13 \\ 
   & 0.5 & -0.55 & 0.16 & -3.47 & 0.00 & -0.86 & -0.20 \\ 
   & 0.9 & 0.37 & 0.18 & 2.04 & 0.04 & 0.06 & 0.63 \\ 
   & 0.95 & 0.01 & 0.29 & 0.04 & 0.97 & -0.51 & 0.75 \\ 
   & 0.99 & 0.49 & 0.40 & 1.22 & 0.22 & -1.77 & 1.06 \\ 
  GSCI & 0.01 & -0.30 & 0.35 & -0.88 & 0.38 & -1.33 & 0.54 \\ 
   & 0.05 & -0.62 & 0.25 & -2.46 & 0.01 & -0.99 & 0.04 \\ 
   & 0.1 & -0.11 & 0.20 & -0.56 & 0.58 & -0.47 & 0.27 \\ 
   & 0.5 & -0.55 & 0.14 & -3.86 & 0.00 & -0.82 & -0.23 \\ 
   & 0.9 & -0.45 & 0.19 & -2.33 & 0.02 & -1.01 & -0.14 \\ 
   & 0.95 & -0.85 & 0.37 & -2.33 & 0.02 & -1.85 & -0.05 \\ 
   & 0.99 & -2.18 & 0.46 & -4.79 & 0.00 & -3.59 & 0.02 \\ 
  LPremium40 & 0.01 & 0.17 & 0.09 & 1.98 & 0.05 & -0.05 & 0.36 \\ 
   & 0.05 & 0.16 & 0.05 & 2.89 & 0.00 & 0.09 & 0.27 \\ 
   & 0.1 & 0.13 & 0.04 & 2.93 & 0.00 & 0.07 & 0.20 \\ 
   & 0.5 & 0.08 & 0.03 & 2.61 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.13 \\ 
   & 0.9 & -0.07 & 0.05 & -1.38 & 0.17 & -0.13 & 0.05 \\ 
   & 0.95 & -0.10 & 0.06 & -1.67 & 0.10 & -0.25 & 0.01 \\ 
   & 0.99 & -0.08 & 0.07 & -1.14 & 0.25 & -0.21 & 0.11 \\ 
   \bottomrule
   }
```

Only the first table is placed on top of the page, with the second table on the middle of the next...... Do not understand why?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `width` (or the `maxwidth`) key you can specify the total width of your table; this requires using one or more `X` column specifier (from the `tabularx` package.) Please refer to the documentation of `ctable` and `tabularx` for further details.

You can use the `\setupctable` command to declare common options for all your `ctable`s. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}                  
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\setupctable{
 doinside=\small\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2},
width=0.9\textwidth,
pos=ht
}    

\begin{document}

\ctable[caption=test one,pos=ht,]
{p{6cm}YYl}
{\tnote[]{note describing the table}}
{\lipsum[1] & col2a & col3a & col4a}

\ctable[caption=test two]
{p{6cm}YY}
{\tnote[]{note describing the table}}
{test text to show the constant width of the first column & column2a with some text & column3a}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.7 \setupctable Do not understand why?

Comment: @latexmp: Most probably outdated package(s). Here's the version of `ctable` in my system:   `ctable.sty    2011/05/01 v1.19 ctable package`. Update your package(s) if needed (meanwhile, you can specify the options for each `ctable` individually).

Comment: ok will do. thnks.